# Is the requirement for a specific wattage of PSU more or less down to graphics card?

Tags: power-supply

When selecting a PSU is the primary motivation to go for a higher wattage PSU based on the specific graphics card and/or number of graphics cards (SLI, crossfire)?

In other words are all other components in a computer relatively negligible in their PSU requirements compared with a modern graphics card?

Note: I'm talking about a Mid to Enthusiast Gaming PC with a config similar to i5, 4 gigs of ram, GTX 275, WD Velociraptor drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words are all other
>   components in a computer relatively
>   negligible in their PSU requirements
>   compared with a modern graphics card?

no, they're not negligible, you can use **[Newegg's online PSU calculator](http://c1.neweggimages.com/BizIntell/tool/psucalc/index.html?cm_sp=Cat32_PowerSupply_left-_-PowerSupplyFinder030510-_-http%3a%2f%2fpromotions.newegg.com%2fproductfinders%2fpowersupply.jpg)**. you will see how each component adds to the PSU requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The graphics card is often the biggest power user, but other components can be significant (especially the CPU).

I suggest using this power calculator: http://www.thermaltake.outervision.com/